# Selecting one node from similar nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I tried searching but came up empty.  It seems so simple but I'm stuck.

Basically I have records that I used the Muenchian grouping but I need to select only or the other.

As in the case below:  I want only one occurence of ID that has the Name - Blue.  The sample below should pick ID 1234 that is Blue and ignore the other ID 1234 with Name = Red.  Same with the last ID 5555. Position could be random.  To top it off, I need to have this also put in a CSV format.

When I apply the Muenchian grouping on ID, running into problems trying to

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

```
<Table>
<Record>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Blue</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>111111</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Red</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>212121</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>2222</ID>
    <Name>Hazel</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>4424233</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>3333</ID>
    <Name>Purple</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>23234</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>4444</ID>
    <Name>Brown</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>76567567</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>5555</ID>
    <Name>Green</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>3456356</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>5555</ID>
    <Name>Blue</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>324342</Number>
</Record>
```

Output should be:

```
<Table>
<Record>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Name>Blue</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>111111</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>2222</ID>
    <Name>Orange</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>4424233</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>3333</ID>
    <Name>Silver</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>23234</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>4444</ID>
    <Name>Blue</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>76567567</Number>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ID>5555</ID>
    <Name>Blue</Name>
    <Status>Available</Status>
    <Number>3456356</Number>
</Record>
```

Update:  I figured a way to do this w/o using Muenchian Grouping and works for specifically this case.  But I was wondering if there was a better way to go about it and if Muenchian Grouping would work. The problem I ran into Muenchian grouping is to determine which stage the grouping it was in this case the first occurrence or second.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:text>IDNumber,Name,Status,Number</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ID = following-sibling::Record[1]/ID and Name = 'Blue'"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Status"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="ID = following-sibling::Record[1]/ID and Name != 'Blue' and following-sibling::Record[1]/Name != 'Blue'"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Status"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="ID = following-sibling::Record[1]/ID and Name !='Blue'"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/ID"/><xsl:text>,          </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/Name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/Status"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/Number"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>  
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="ID != preceding-sibling::Record[1]/ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Status"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>                          
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>               
            </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you provide a better formulation of the requirements? The example is rather small, and your own solution is rather confusing.

Comment: Let me see if I can make this a bit more clearer:  If 2 identical ID's exist, I need to keep the node that has the Name='Blue'.  The identical nodes are adjacent but the node containing 'Blue' can be in first or second matching ID's.  If only 1 unique ID exists, I just keep it.

Comment: Would it be correct to restate this as: for each unique ID, output exactly one node; if one (or more?) of the nodes is Blue, then output that node (or the first one of those nodes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work for you;

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="records-by-id" match="Record" use="ID" />

<xsl:template match="/Table">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <xsl:text>IDNumber,Name,Status,Number&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- FOR EACH DISTINCT ID: -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[count(. | key('records-by-id', ID)[1]) = 1]">
        <!-- TAKE THE RECORDS IN CURRENT GROUP ... -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('records-by-id', ID)">
            <!-- .. SORT THEM BY "BLUENESS" ... -->
            <xsl:sort select="Name='Blue'" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
            <!-- ... AND OUTPUT THE FIRST RECORD IN THE (SORTED) GROUP -->
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:call-template name="row"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="row">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result is:

```
IDNumber,Name,Status,Number
1234,Blue,Available,111111
2222,Hazel,Available,4424233
3333,Purple,Available,23234
4444,Brown,Available,76567567
5555,Blue,Available,324342
```

Comment: Hi and thanks.  Yes, this is what I was trying to do but got stuck with sorting and such.  So I ended doing what I posted but I like this much better!