# Isolate highest value per user ID using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have ordered a set of records in the ascending order of "userId" and descending order of "collectorValue".

I need to isolate the highest/topmost "collectorValue" record for each "userId". I am looking to achieve this through XSLT.

My source XML is like so:

```
<TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>4</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>2</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1103429</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>5</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
</TimeCollector>
```

My target XML should look like so:

```
<TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>4</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1103429</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
<TimeCollector>
  <collectorValue>5</collectorValue>
  <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
  <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
</TimeCollector>
</TimeCollector>
```

I am new to XSLT and am in need of help to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: This is first of all a *grouping* problem - start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. To get the maximum value in each group, you can apply the method shown in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577765/3016153

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

> I have ordered a set of records in the ascending order of "userId" and descending order of "collectorValue".

It's not clear what exactly you mean by that. If the input XML is already sorted the way you describe, then all you need to do is pick the first record in each group by `userId`. This is easy to do using the first step of the [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) method:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="tc" match="TimeCollector" use="userId"/>

<xsl:template match="/TimeCollector">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="TimeCollector[count(. | key('tc', userId)[1]) = 1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using Muenchian grouping method as an algorithm for grouping.

It is much better to start using XSLT processor that is conformance with XSLT standards: 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TimeCollector>
    <TimeCollector>
        <collectorValue>4</collectorValue>
        <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
        <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </TimeCollector>
    <TimeCollector>
        <collectorValue>2</collectorValue>
        <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
        <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </TimeCollector>
    <TimeCollector>
        <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
        <userId>UAT1103429</userId>
        <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </TimeCollector>
    <TimeCollector>
        <collectorValue>5</collectorValue>
        <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
        <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </TimeCollector>
    <TimeCollector>
        <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
        <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
        <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </TimeCollector>
</TimeCollector>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="TimeCollectorKey" match="TimeCollector/TimeCollector" use="userId"/>

    <xsl:template match="/TimeCollector">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="TimeCollector[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('TimeCollectorKey', userId)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="userId" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="collectorValue" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<TimeCollector>
  <TimeCollector>
    <collectorValue>4</collectorValue>
    <userId>UAT1101767</userId>
    <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
  </TimeCollector>
  <TimeCollector>
    <collectorValue>3</collectorValue>
    <userId>UAT1103429</userId>
    <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
  </TimeCollector>
  <TimeCollector>
    <collectorValue>5</collectorValue>
    <userId>UAT1103746</userId>
    <startDate>2023-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
  </TimeCollector>
</TimeCollector>
```

Comment: This does not return the highest value - it returns the first one.

Comment: It is producing the OP desired output.

Comment: Only by coincidence. Or perhaps you are assuming that the input is already sorted as stated by OP - in that case you are overcomplicating the process.